# copy a whole row from one matrix into another using vba

Tags: vba, excel

in one part of my code I read a matrix

```
Dim matr As Variant, mat As Variant, vec As Variant
matr = Worksheets("portfolio").Range("A2:K163")
```

now after two `if-loops` I would like to copy the whole row into a new matrix

```
For i = 1 To lngRow
    For j = 2 To ingRow
        If matr(i, 11) = matr(j, 11) Then
            If matr(i, 4) = matr(j, 4) Then
                matr(j,...)=mat(j,...)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

How can one copy the whole row from the existing matrix to another one?

Comment: there is no magic solution, you will need to loop through all elements inside that `j` and copy them one by one. Or, you could copy it to a Worksheet, and then copy the new array from that Range.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request correctly, here is some code which should help you. I've commented it for explanation.

The main gist is this: `mat` grows in rows dynamically so that it can contain a new row of data from `matr`. Then this row is copied across.

Of course if you allow `mat` to be initialised to the same size as `matr` and have many empty rows, you can ignore all the work with `ReDim` and **just use the loop at the bottom to copy a row**.

Edit: I've edited this to take note of `Preserve`. From the docs, `Preserve` can only be used changing the last dimension. Because this isn't the case here, the data is copied to a temp array before new row is added.

```
    Option Base 1

Sub rr()

    ' Initialise 2D array to a range
    Dim matr As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D7")
    matr = rng

    ' Range used so column count can be fetched easily
    Dim colCount As Long
    colCount = rng.Columns.Count

    ' Initialise empty 2D array for populating with given rows from matr
    Dim mat() As Variant
    Dim matTemp() As Variant

    ' Test conditions simplified for demo
    Dim someCondition As Boolean
    someCondition = True

    ' upper bound of mat, for testing if it is dimensioned
    Dim ub As Long
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    Dim rowToCopy As Long

    For rowToCopy = 1 To 2

        If someCondition = True Then

            ' test if dimensioned already
            ub = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            ub = UBound(mat)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If ub = 0 Then
            ' if no, dimension it to 1 row
                ReDim mat(1, colCount)
            Else
            ' if yes, dimension it to 1 extra row
                ReDim matTemp(ub + 1, colCount)
                For m = 1 To ub
                    For n = 1 To colCount
                        matTemp(m, n) = mat(m, n)
                    Next n
                Next m
                ReDim mat(ub + 1, colCount)
                mat = matTemp
            End If

            ' Assign 'columns' of 2D array matr to new array mat
            For m = 1 To colCount
                mat(ub + 1, m) = matr(rowToCopy, m)
            Next m

        End If

    Next rowToCopy

End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not help, I found the solution with Excel. I renounce to apply for this problem  the vba!

Comment: @maniA You should post the solution as an answer then in case it helps others, and this question isn't permanently unanswered.